# How to mock postgres Tagged Template Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, npm, jestjs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/postgres

How to mock sql in a unit test for example,

```
const olderThan = x => sql`and age > ${ x }`

const filterAge = true

await sql`
  select
   *
  from users
  where name is not null ${
    filterAge
      ? olderThan(50)
      : sql``
  }
`
```

Comment: Don't? Mock out this persistence layer when unit-testing business logic that relies on it, but this code is coupled entirely to the DB and should be integration tested.